# Apple push notification coding on ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to buid a push notification sistem for an ios app, now my problem is that everywhere I look they only show how to genereate the certificate but on MAC OS, but I'm on ubuntu 13.04.
Can any one please tell me how to create the certificate on a ubuntu OS ??

1. I already got the csr and the key from my computer.
2. Uploaded it to mac and generated the certificate.
3. Downloaded the .cer from mac.

Now the next step they say is to add the cer to the keychain on mac, but I don't have a MAC, how can i do it???

Comment: How are you developing an iOS app if you don't have a MAC OS?

Comment: im not developing the app, im developing the cms + API for the app

Comment: Why don't you ask the person developing the app to generate the certificate and send you the `p12` or `pem` file (whichever your server code prefers)?

Comment: the problem is that i need to create a certificate but for the server, since i already ask my friend to build the sertificate and the conection gives me a hanshake error.

Comment: Then either your friend made a mistake when creating the certificate or gave you the wrong password for it. You need a push certificate for your server. Your friend should follow the instructions [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW1) in order to generate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had the same problem today. This question and the comment and my old experience solved this nightmare. I was on mobile dev with mac, and my colleague at server side Ubuntu.

There is the [Creating the SSL Certificate and Keys](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW1) description and [tutorial for server side](http://blog.serverdensity.com/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/).

You can stuck days and days and wandering what is wrong, why isn't working, search for error messages and re-create certifications and still low chance to get working.

In our case the solution it was:

- needed to download one certificate from Entrust, which usually isn't at tutorials.
- **Clear all previous certificates,** provisioning profiles from XCode and keychain on mac related to that company, developer.
- **Restart Mac.** You can wonder why needed this, why isn't enough to remove. Just restart it.
- Do the steps with import to keychain
- Do the steps with exports
- Do the console steps

Now the server side can connect to APNS no certificate, no handshake eror.

Regarding this question it is a clear situation as the certificates are wrong.
Just do the steps suggested, our case solved with this.

> Uploaded it to mac and generated the certificate.

=>  you have a mac access

> but I don't have a MAC, how can i do it???

must use that mac.